# Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

What is wrong with this code snippet? i am getting Segmentation fault!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        struct {
                char* name;
                int age;
        } *emp;
        char* empname = "Kumar";
        int empage = 31;
        emp->name = empname;
        emp->age = empage;
        printf("empname :%s\n",emp->name);
        printf("empage :%d",emp->age);
        return 0;
}
```

And how to correct this program to work?

Comment: You need to get a book on C programming and learn about pointers. It's important to get the basics straight from the beginning, or it *will* cause trouble for you later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not allocating memory for `emp`. Before using `emp`, try

```
emp = malloc(sizeof(*emp));
```

Comment: sizeof(emp), otherwise you get the size of a pointer...

Comment: @yankee No, `emp` is the pointer, `*emp` is the object pointed to :-)

Comment: Ok, learned something about C today :-).

Comment: @nil To format my post, do i need to just place my code in a pair of ` ? like `emp = malloc(sizeof(emp));` or stackoverflow does have any document or tool to do that befor posting? Further, it is long time i used c and lost basics, you are right. I am currently using java language these days. Also, can you point me to the rules (posting rules ) of StackOverflow?

Comment: @vchitta http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

if you test your code putting in compilation -Wall, the terminal says you that 'emp' is uninitialized therefore you must allocate in dynamic way 'emp' (malloc etc. etc.).

```
int len_struct = sizeof(*emp);
emp = malloc(len_struct);
```

**PS**: This is my advice : i prefer create a struct in *global memory* (in *Data*) because i think that this struct you would use in future in the prg.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use pointer to `struct` nor `printf`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("empname :Kumar");
    puts("empage :30");
    return 0;
}
```